# Not working valet php command to proxy calls on Macbook M1

Tags: apple-m1, laravel-valet, valet

if I run the command

`valet php -v` or `valet composer install`

i am getting an error:

`/opt/homebrew/bin/valet: line 158: Fatal: command not found`

Other teams are working. The problem is only with the proxy. Suggest options for solving this problem for M1